# Real time notifications on iOS

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS app which needs to receive regular data from the server at specific period of time (every 5 seconds).

Apple gives developers some choices for background working.

I convinced that `Background Fetch` is the proper method for my problem.
But when I tested it I got confused.
`Background Fetch` has many issues with my requirements:

1. It does not fetch data at period you defined when declared it:
   `application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)`
   I tried this and this:
   `application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(5)`. But no guarantee
   that your app will fetch data at this interval.
2. When the screen is off, your app will not make any fetch until the
       phone is unlocked again.

I wonder if there is a way that let my app receives real time data (or at least every 5 seconds).

**Note:** I read about `remote notifications` and I do not guarantee that I can execute it now, So I am searching for other solutions.

Thanks

Comment: This is not really possible on iOS. The main reason is that this will drain the battery. So you should ask yourself is it really necessary to fetch data every 5 seconds? If this is to make sure that the user does not miss any information you might just want to send a push notification to the users device when important data is available.

Comment: I think you need a different approach, maybe using socket.io? As they say : Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication. You establish a connection between the server and your app and interact on events. I used on one of my apps and it is very easy to setup.
In my case, the app was active while interacting with the server. [http://socket.io/]

Comment: do you mean by push notification the same as remote notification? @rckoenes

Comment: ok, but when your app goes background what happen to the socket ? @Lucho

Comment: Yes, Push notification which you might call remote notification. @Lucho socket.io will not work when the app is in the background.

Comment: I wonder, what is the techniques used by global social app, like whatsapp and telegram?

Comment: @wajeeh when the app goes to background state, you have a few more minutes, then the connections gets killed. You could use the notifications then. Here is a link explaining background fetch, etc. maybe it helps. [https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/multitasking/]

Comment: @Lucho your link does not work, I need my app to work most of the time,

Comment: @wajeeh https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/multitasking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this problem until writing this answer.

If I need a real time notification then I must use `Push Notification`.

There is no way to check for server data every period of time from the app only, I can send a `Remote Notification` when new data available on server to wake up the app and let it connect to the server.